# What does the second parameter of the splice method do?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand the point of having the second parameter in the splice method.

var example = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

example.splice(0,1)

Looking at articles and it says the second parameter determines how many item get removed. But it seems to me that there is always only one item in a single position.

What is the point of indicating how many items you want to delete when there will only be one item in a single position?Can you have multiple items in a single indice/index?

Comment: Did you check the reference on MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Oh ok so this is a bit tricky. When you indicate a number bigger than 1 in the second parameter, it means to delete the item that has been replaced into the indice that was deleted through the iteration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
```

The documentation says that the second paramter determines how many elements you want to delete. So you might use it to delete 2 or more entries from an array with this at a specific position.